# iSrcoll4 - show scrollbar by default

Tags: javascript, ipad, iscroll4

I'm using iScroll4 to show custom scrollbar for iOS devices. I observe that the scrollbars are not visible by default and only appears when the user scrolls the content. Is there an option to show scrollbars by default on page load in iOS devices?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var iOS = false,   p = navigator.platform;

if( p === 'iPad' || p === 'iPhone' || p === 'iPod' ){
        iOS = true;
}


if(iOS == true){

function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);    
window.onload = function() { setTimeout(function () { loaded(); }, 1500)};  
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your iscroll.js file, around line 112 there is a line:

```
hideScrollbar: isIDevice,
```

Change it to:

```
hideScrollbar: false,
```